# Jquery .on Method Inconsistently Nonresponsive

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons directly on top of each other. Each one shows its respective div and hides the other radio's div. Everything about them is the same except the names - "#fed" works , "#state" doesn't. Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="jur" id="fed" /> Federal</label>
        <span class="searchtype" id="feddiv"></span>

<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="jur" id="state" /> State</label>         
        <span class="searchtype" id="statediv" ></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#state').on('click',function(event) {
    $('#statediv').show();
    $('#feddiv').hide();
});
$('#fed').on('click',function(event) {
    $('#feddiv').show();
    $('#statediv').hide();
});
```

Comment: Do you have the id `#state` duplicated anywhere else in the code? Otherwise this should work. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HQPbF/

Comment: I've tested your example verbatim, http://jsfiddle.net/gbAdD/ and it seems to work perfectly

Comment: that was it - im living dangerously and holding user info as hidden variables instead of session variables and one of them is state. thanks!

Comment: @user988129 Yes that is the issue. it would have selected the first one with #statediv appearing in DOM...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.on('click', function(){});` why not use `.click(function(){});` ?

Also, set the **ID** in 'label' and not the 'input', just so that the person can click on the text to hide the rest.

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer.